# Delegate method not being sent

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don´t understand why the delegate is not sent the message mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:

In viewDidLoad i ask the mapView to startUpdating with setShowUserLocation:YES. But it´s like it never accomplish this.

Any suggestions?

```
#import "TrackViewController.h"
#import "MainWindowViewController.h"



@class MainWindowViewController;
@implementation TrackViewController

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSLog(@"Init trackcontriller");
    self=[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if(self){

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];


    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction) back:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) findLocation;
{
    NSLog(@"findlocation");
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void) foundLocation:(CLLocation *)loc
{
    NSLog(@"Foundlocation");
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [loc coordinate];

    MKCoordinateRegion region =  MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 100, 100);
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];


    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    [worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [worldView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];

}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSLog(@"mapview didupdateUserlocation");
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 200, 200);
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

-(void)dealloc 
{

     [locationManager setDelegate:nil];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager
 didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
// Deprecated i know
{
     NSLog(@"Locationanager didupdate tolocation from location");


NSTimeInterval t = [[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow];

if(t<-180){
    return;
}

    [self foundLocation:newLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you set this class to be the delegate of the map view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you mix up the location services of `CLLocationManager` and of `MapView`. `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` is a delegate method of `MKMapView`. If you just need this method to update the user's location, you don't have to instantiate a `CLLocationManager`. Instead you simply say, as you did, `[worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];`
But of course, your object that implements `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` has to be the delegate of you `MKMapView` object, here of `worldView`, not of a `CLLocationManager` object!
So my suggestion is to set your `TrackViewController` object as the delegate of your `MKMapView` object, i.e. of `worldView`, and delete the code related to the `CLLocationManager`.

Comment: I set the delegate of the mapView in the xib. It makes sense not to mix up CLLocationManager and MapView. Its weird though - this code is pretty much copied from Big Nerd Ranch IOS programming version 3. Why would they mix it up, if its not correct. As it is now, does the locationManager serve no purpose at all?

Comment: Your code uses a CLLocationManager to periodically update the region of the mapView. The same could be done much easier by using the tracking mode options of MKMapView. Anyway, when your code finds a new location, it stops the location manager that uses the core location services. But these are also used by MKMapView. I am not sure, but it might be that stopping the location manager also stops mapView from updating the user location, and mapView:didUpdateUserLocation: is no longer called. You could out comment [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; and check if the callback comes through.

Comment: BTW I assume worldView is a retained/strong property, so that it is not released before it can do the callback?